# Программное добавление динамически изменяющегося TextView в LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, android-textview

Инициализирую LinearLayout, TextView

```
linearLayout=new LinearLayout(context);
    textView=new TextView(context);
    textView.setText(text);
    textView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, Const.hintSize);
    textView.setTypeface(Assets.font);
    textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    textView.setMaxWidth(width);
    textView.setMaxHeight(height);
    textView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
    linearLayout.measure(width,height);
    linearLayout.layout(0,0,width,height);
    textView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            lineCount=textView.getLineCount();
            max=Const.hintSize*lineCount;
        }
    });
    Log.d("lineCount",lineCount+"");
```

В логе

```
D/lineCount﹕ 0
```

Обращаемся к документации `getLineCount()`

> Return the number of lines of text, or 0 if the internal Layout has not been built.

Значит, лэйаут не был построен, так как его построить?

Comment: Этот кусок кода взят из onCreate?

Comment: Из конструктора собственного класса ScrollableText

Comment: getLineCount() Вам вернет значение, только когда ваша вью(ScrollableText) уже лежит  в разметке

Comment: Что значит "лежит"? Отрисована на канвасе (в моем случае) или что?

Comment: А если так? postDelayed(Runnable, long)?

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Comment: Перенесите `Log.d("lineCount",lineCount+"");` вовнутрь `run()`

Comment: Я обошелся бы без `lineCount`, если бы Log.d работал внутри `run()`

Comment: Ура я понял где ошибка, runnable не запускается

Answer (score 1):

Подпишитесь на изменение в [дереве view](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html) (т.е. когда все view перестроятся), в нем получайте lineCount...

```
textView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
    new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // Не забываем отписываться, притом сразу
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
                textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            } else {
                textView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            }
            lineCount=textView.getLineCount();
            max=Const.hintSize*lineCount;
            Log.d("lineCount",lineCount+"");
        }
    });
```